# Sort and filter a list of objects

Tags: java, collections

I defined a `Product` class like this:

```
public class Product {
    String name;
    ProductType type;
    BigDecimal price;
    // Getters and Setters omitted
}
```

With the `ProductType` as an `enum` class:

```
public enum ProductType {
    APPLE, PEAR, BANANA
}
```

Now I have created a `List<Product>` where I added all kinds of products. What I would like to do is to be able to sort this list on price and filter it on type.

What are the standard ways to implement this kind of behavior?

Comment: Yes, you make Product implement  Comparable so they can be sorted

Comment: @cricket_007 Hmmm ... I would not let `Product` implement the `Comparable` interface. Classes should only implement that if there is a _natural order_ of it's instances. This could be somewhat difficult for the products, here. Better: Have one or more `Comparator`s that can be used for sorting.

Comment: @Seelenvirtouse Agreed, the sorting could be implemented by any attribute. I was simply saying that is a standard way to implement a behavior of sorting a collection

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Java 8:

```
List<Product> products = // ...
List<Product> filterSortedProdycts = 
    products.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getType() == ProductType.BANANA)  // only keep BANANA
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Product::getPrice)) // sort by price
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @MatthiasSteinbauer answer, you can use Java 8 stream for both [sorting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) and [filer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-).

Sorting:

```
products.stream()
        .sorted((p1, p2) -> p1.getPrice().compareTo(p2.getPrice())).collect(toList());
```

Filtering:

```
products.stream().filter(p -> p.getType().equals(givenType)).collect(toList());
```

Comment: This is pretty vague. Could you edit this to add a relevant sample of code that solves the problem? Just linking to pages on other sites isn't considered acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8, I would say the following is the most standard method of filtering by type and sorting on price:

```
Stream<Product> results = products.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getType() == ProductType.BANANA)
            .sorted((l, r) -> l.getPrice().compareTo(r.getPrice()));
```

In Java 7, which lacks Streams and Lambdas, I would recommend using [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava). For which the following would work:

```
ImmutableList<Product> results = FluentIterable.from(products).filter(new Predicate<Product>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Product input) {
        return input.getType() == ProductType.BANANA;
    }
}).toSortedList(new Comparator<Product>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {
        return o1.getPrice().compareTo(o2.getPrice());
    }
});
```

I would probably refactor the anonymous inner classes into named classes for readability.

Please note, in both cases a new list with the results is created.

Comment: does order of .filter() vs .sorted() call affect performance?

Answer (score 0):

In general you could use the `Collections.sort` method together with implementing `Sortable` on your class. Or you use the more modern streaming API which provides a more streamlined programming interface and allows for automatic optimization such as facilitating multiple processors.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Java libraries provide `Collections.sort()` for one-shot sorting and `TreeSet` and `TreeMap` for permanently sorted collections.

Answer (score 0):

*Collections.sort* is the standard way

You may also use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library:

Take a look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4258874/3042207)