# Sorting unique objects on basis of other states

Tags: java

I have collection of employees with states as name,salary,id.

```
    TreeSet ts=new TreeSet();
    ts.add(new Employee("neeraj", 10000, 123));
    ts.add(new Employee("neeraj", 10000, 789));
    ts.add(new Employee("ankit", 30000, 345));
    ts.add(new Employee("ankit", 40000, 456));
```

How to sort employees with unique name on basis of salary?

Comment: Implement `Comparator` interface and use this implementation along with your collection upon sorting.

Comment: The [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4258700/5221149) is old, but does have a Java 8 answer [further down](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36367245/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

**Java 8 solution:**

```
Collections.sort(employees, Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName)
    .thenComparing(Report::getSalary));
```

Comment: That will sort *purely* by `salary`. OP wants to *"sort employees **with unique name** on basis of salary"*, i.e. sort *primarily* by `name`, *secondarily* by `salary`.

Comment: how to check unique names?

Comment: @Andreas Yea, right you are. Thank's, i've edited my answer.

Comment: can it done by overriding equals method?

Comment: @NeerajThakur No, either implement `Comparable<Employee>` and the `compareTo` method, or provide a `Comparator<Employee>`, e.g. as shown in this answer for Java 8, or as shown in the [duplicate link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4258700/5221149).