# Sort by predefined priority order using comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I have the following problem to solve. I am using Java.

A restaurant recognizes 3 types of customers: “NEWBIES”, “REGULARS” and “VIPs”. When customers place their orders, all the orders join a queue. However the orders are always served in such a way that VIPs are served before regulars who are served before newbies.

I need a class which could be used to sort the customer orders. In case two customers are of the same type, the orderID should be used to sort them.

How can I sort by order priority based on the customer type using comparator?

Assuming I already have the following class Order

```
public class Order
{
    public static int orderID;
    private int tableNumber;
    private String[] orderDetails;
    private String customerType;

    public Order(int tableNumber, String[] orderDetails, String customerType)
    {
        this.tableNumber = tableNumber;
        this.orderDetails = orderDetails;
        this.customerType = customerType;
        orderID += 1;
    }
    // get and set methods declared
}
```

I have implemented the comparator as follows:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class OrderComparator implements Comparator<Order>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Order o1, Order o2)
    {
        if(o1.getType().equals(o2.getType()))
            return o1.getOrderID - o2.getOrderID;
        else
        // How does comparing the customer type text ensure that 
        // it will be printed in the right order?
            return o1.getType().compareTo(o2.getType());
    }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i updated the question @NomadMaker. I have tried implementing the comparator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only do you want to [sort on multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258700/collections-sort-with-multiple-fields/4258738), you also want a custom sort with one of those fields.

In the code below, I filled in the missing parts of both class `Order` and class `OrderComparator`. Notes after the code.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Order {
    public static final String  NEWBIES = "NEWBIES";
    public static final String  REGULARS = "REGULARS";
    public static final String  VIP = "VIP";

    private static int  orderId;

    private int orderID;
    private int tableNumber;
    private String[] orderDetails;
    private String customerType;

    public Order(int tableNumber, String[] orderDetails, String customerType) {
        this.tableNumber = tableNumber;
        this.orderDetails = orderDetails;
        this.customerType = customerType;
        orderID = ++orderId;
    }

    public int getOrderID() {
        return orderID;
    }

    public int getTableNumber() {
        return tableNumber;
    }

    public String[] getOrderDetails() {
        return orderDetails;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return customerType;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d %s", orderID, customerType);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Order order1 = new Order(0, null, VIP);
        Order order2 = new Order(0, null, REGULARS);
        Order order3 = new Order(0, null, REGULARS);
        List<Order> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(order3);
        list.add(order2);
        list.add(order1);
        System.out.println("Unordered: " + list);
        Collections.sort(list, new OrderComparator());
        System.out.println("Ordered: " + list);
    }
}

class OrderComparator implements Comparator<Order> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Order o1, Order o2) {
        if (o1.getType().equals(o2.getType())) {
            return o1.getOrderID() - o2.getOrderID();
        }
        else {
            if (Order.VIP.equals(o1.getType())) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (Order.VIP.equals(o2.getType())) {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (Order.REGULARS.equals(o1.getType())) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (Order.REGULARS.equals(o2.getType())) {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (Order.NEWBIES.equals(o1.getType())) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (Order.NEWBIES.equals(o2.getType())) {
                return 1;
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected customer type.");
        }
    }
}
```

- I added method `main` to class `Order` in order to test the code.
- I added method `toString` to class `Order` so as to be able to check whether the code produces the expected results.
- I understand that you want a kind of numerator for `Order` objects. Hence I made member `orderID` an instance member since every `Order` has its own ID and I added a new static member `orderId` (note that Java is case sensitive) which produces a new, unique order ID for each new `Order` object.
- You want VIP orders to come before REGULARS orders and you want REGULARS orders to come before NEWBIES orders. By default, a `Comparator` sorts by ascending order, hence you want VIP to be lowest and NEWBIES to be highest (purely for sorting purposes). So in method `compare` (of class `OrderComparator`), if, for example, the type of `o1` is VIP and the type of `o2` is REGULARS then you want VIP to be lower that REGULAR. Hence in that situation, method `compare` returns -1 (minus one).

Running the above code produces the following output.

```
Unordered: [3 REGULARS, 2 REGULARS, 1 VIP]
Ordered: [1 VIP, 2 REGULARS, 3 REGULARS]
```

---

Note that since `customerType` (in class `Order`) is a `String`, there is a chance that an `Order` object will be created with an invalid `customerType` value. You could change the constructor of class `Order` and add a check for the supplied value (for `customerType`) and throw an `Exception` if the supplied value is invalid. Or you could use [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) (also known as [enumerated types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/enum.html)). The below code uses `enum` instead of `String` for `customerType` - which also simplifies method `compare` in class `OrderComparator`.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Order {
    private static int  orderId;

    private int orderID;
    private int tableNumber;
    private String[] orderDetails;
    private CustomerType customerType;

    public Order(int tableNumber, String[] orderDetails, CustomerType customerType) {
        this.tableNumber = tableNumber;
        this.orderDetails = orderDetails;
        this.customerType = customerType;
        orderID = ++orderId;
    }

    public int getOrderID() {
        return orderID;
    }

    public int getTableNumber() {
        return tableNumber;
    }

    public String[] getOrderDetails() {
        return orderDetails;
    }

    public CustomerType getType() {
        return customerType;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d %s", orderID, customerType);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Order order1 = new Order(0, null, CustomerType.VIP);
        Order order2 = new Order(0, null, CustomerType.REGULARS);
        Order order3 = new Order(0, null, CustomerType.REGULARS);
        List<Order> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(order3);
        list.add(order2);
        list.add(order1);
        System.out.println("Unordered: " + list);
        Collections.sort(list, new OrderComparator());
        System.out.println("Ordered: " + list);
    }
}

class OrderComparator implements Comparator<Order> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Order o1, Order o2) {
        if (o1.getType().equals(o2.getType())) {
            return o1.getOrderID() - o2.getOrderID();
        }
        else {
            return o2.getType().ordinal() - o1.getType().ordinal();
        }
    }
}

enum CustomerType {
    NEWBIES, REGULARS, VIP
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read this question [How to sort a collection by multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258700/collections-sort-with-multiple-fields/4258738). Especially the second answer, first option listed.

Comment: But for example if i do the following:
return o1.getType().compareTo(o2.getType()). How does this ensure that the VIP will be output before Regulars and newbies simply based on text comparison.

Comment: For cases like this (you have a finite collection of constants), you should use an Enum to represent your 3 types of guest. The default comparator for string is indeed inappropriate. For enums, its natural ordering is the order of declaration, so you just have to declare the types in order of importance.