# How to sort a collection by two criteria？

Tags: java, algorithm

There is a list with several elements. The elements in it has two criteria: `id` and `value`. I want to sort them by `value` and get first three elements, then put the elements which `id != 1` to the end of the list.

for example：

```
class Test {
    int id;
    int value;

    public Test(int id, int value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

```
Test a = new Test(1,4);
Test b = new Test(2,3);
Test c = new Test(1,1);
Test d = new Test(2,5);
```

```
origin list: a,b,c,d
```

sort by `value` and get first three elements:
c,b,a

put the elements which `id != 1` to the end of the list:
c,a,b

how to implement it in a efficient and elegant way?

Comment: Use a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) as a starting point

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258700/collections-sort-with-multiple-fields/20093589) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/how-to-sort-by-two-fields-in-java/26865122) or just [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+sort+collection+by+multiple+fields&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) might help

Comment: Very similar questions have been asked and answered before. Please search.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this in one line, using `stream`. You would need `sorted` to sort elements and `limit` to take first three elements. First sort by `value`, then take first three elements, then sort by `id` to move element with `id != 1` to the end and store result in some collection.

```
class Test {
    int id;
    int value;

    public Test(int id, int value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test a=new Test(1,4);
        Test b=new Test(2,3);
        Test c=new Test(1,1);
        Test d=new Test(2,5);

        List<Test> result = Stream.of(a, b, c, d)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(x -> x.value))
                .limit(3)
                .sorted((x, y) -> {
                    if(x.id == 1 && y.id != 1) {
                        return -1;
                    }

                    if(y.id == 1 && x.id != 1) {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    return 0;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Output

```
[Test{id=1, value=1}, Test{id=1, value=4}, Test{id=2, value=3}]
```