# compare more field of a object in compareTo

Tags: java, compareto

I'd compare more than one only field of a object using the `compareTo` method. Is it possible?

for istance:

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return field.compareTo(o.field);
}
```

I create this method to sort a collection. Obviously my object has to implement `Comparable` interface.

I'm guessing if is possible to compare not only one field in the same method `compareTo`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to compare objects by multiple fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/best-way-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible.  If the result of comparing the first field returns zero, then return the result of comparing the second field.

```
public int compareTo(SomeClass o) {
    int result = field1.compareTo(o.field1);
    if ( result == 0 ) {
        result = field2.compareTo(o.field2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This gets cumbersome fairly quickly, which is why Guava provides a [`ComparisonChain`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html). Example use:

```
public int compareTo(SomeClass o) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
         .compare(field1, o.field1)
         .compare(field2, o.field2)
         .result();
}
```

Comment: and also pretty nested really quick, why @aix's Solution should be preferred

Comment: @Simon: If you have more than two, you shouldn't be using either my first solution or aix's; use a helper like I listed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible, for example like so:

```
public int compareTo(MyClass o){
  int ret = field1.compareTo(o.field1);
  if (ret != 0) return ret;
  ret = field2.compareTo(o.field2);
  if (ret != 0) return ret;
  ...
  return fieldN.compareTo(o.fieldN);
}
```

Comment: With generics, it wouldn't be `Object` unless for some very odd reason (like backward compatibility) you have implemented `Comparable<Object>`.

Comment: Reusing that variables is a bit nasty.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly factor in other fields when comparing, but there's typically some order of precedence, just like sorting alphabetically only looks at the second letter if the first is the same:

```
public int compareTo(Object o){

   int comparison = field.compareTo(o.field);
   if (comparison != 0)
      return comparison;
   comparison = field2.compareTo(o.field2);
   if (comparison != 0)
      return comparison;
   //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int compareTo(Object o){
  int res = field.compareTo(o.field);
  if(res==0)
    res=field1.compareTo(o.field1);
  return res;
}
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

sure you can.
however you must define the rule of comparison .

e.g.

you have

```
objectA{a=1;b=2;c=3}
objectB{a=20;b=1;c=6}
```

in your `compareTo(Object o)` method, you could compare `this.fields` with `o.fields`. you can even compare `this.a` to `o.c` if you really need. point is you have to define the rule, in which case objectA < objectB. etc..

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Here's a relatively concise way of doing it.

```
public int compareTo(MyClass other) {
    return
        a!=other.a ? Integer.compare(a, other.a) :
        b!=other.b ? Integer.compare(b, other.b) :
                     Integer.compare(c, other.c);
}
```

(`Integer.compare` is from Java SE 7, but the implementation isn't difficult. Assumes `int` fields `a`, `b`, `c`, but is essentially the same for any field types you can compare.)

Comment: Concise, but you're doing most comparisons twice.  That might be needlessly expensive for non-primitives.

Comment: The equality comparison is likely to be substantially faster in many cases. Substitute `(x<other.x ? -1 : 1)` if you must have absolutely fastest performance.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it any of following ways:

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
{    
    return (field.compareTo(o.field)==1 && field2.compareTo(o.field2)==0)? 0 : 1; 
}
```

OR

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
{
    // add various if-else blocks
    // OR
    // call a separate method    
}
```

Comment: You are returning a boolean instead of an int. And it's just very wrong.

Comment: It still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If you are pointing towards checking for `1` and `0` respectively, i just wanted to show OP that it's possible. logic for comparision he can have whatever he wants.