# Sorting based on compareTo() in SortedSet

Tags: java

Hi this is a question that I found from a book. I am not exactly clear with thing happens in compareTo() method. Tree set is a sorted class. So does it always call to compareTo()?

And inside compareTo() how does sorting is done based on, return age-((Person)0).age ?

```
    package javaapplication1;

    import java.util.NavigableSet;
    import java.util.SortedSet;
    import java.util.TreeSet;


    public class _157 {
        public static void main(String args[]){

            NavigableSet s=new TreeSet();
        for(int i=50;i<55;++i){
        s.add(new Person(i));
        }
        SortedSet s2=s.tailSet(new Person(52));
        System.out.println(s2);
        }
    }

    class Person implements Comparable{
    private int age;
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object t) {
           return ((Person)t).age-age;

        }

        Person(int age){

            this.age=age;

        }
        public String toString(){
        return "Person("+age+")";
        }

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CompareTo Overide Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068350/compareto-overide-sort)

Comment: It's calculating the difference between the incoming `Person` object's age with the current instance of `Person` by subtracting them from each other

Comment: Strictly speaking, that `compareTo` method is wrong. It overflows for large negative values of `age`. Although I suppose people shouldn't have large negative ages...

Comment: At what time compareTo() is called? Is it at the moment where data is added to the TreeSet?

Comment: Do you understand what a `TreeSet` _is_? And how you would go about implementing one? Presumably that would answer your question. Maybe start by reading the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you closely look at the `TreeMap` class in Java for `put` method, a comparison is done for new object before adding in the class.

[Check this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29).

The `compareTo` method which you implemented in your Domain class is used while adding object in a Map. (FYI, TreeSet is ultimately used TreeMap to store the object in sort order).

Any modifying operation ultimately invoke the 'compareTo`method to sort the objects in Map and based on the result of`compareTo` method, the objects are stored.

What compareTo method does in your case : It will compare the age of two person and return the difference between their age and based on this return value the TreeMap is sorted.

So if you use `((Person)t).age-age` as return value, then it will store the person in descending order of their age.

Comment: This isn't right. _Any_ modifying operation on the tree _may_ result in the `compareTo` method of a particular object being called, depending on where that object is in the tree.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The output of this is [Person(52), Person(51), Person(50)]. But when I change return value into age-((Person)t).age, out put changes into [Person(52), Person(53), Person(54)]. How does this change happens. Please kindly explain.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes definitely, `compareTo` method invoke on any modifying operation. I updated the answer. Thanks :)