# sort alphanumeric arraylist in ascending order

Tags: java, collections

how to sort arraylist having elements like

```
02112-S1530   
02112-S1529  
02112-S1531
```

in ascending order.

i am using Collection.sort(List name);
but getting output

```
02112-S1531  
02112-S1529   
02112-S1530
```

Expected output is:

```
02112-S1529  
02112-S1530   
02112-S1531
```

i did like

```
List<String> gbosIdsList = new ArrayList<String>();
gbosIdsList.add("02112-S1530");
gbosIdsList.add("02112-S1529");
gbosIdsList.add("02112-S1531");
Collections.sort(gbosIdsList);
Iterator itr = gbosIdsList.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext()){
      System.out.println(itr.next());           
}
```

Comment: Use comparator to sort alphanumeric arraylist.

Comment: You need to define your own `comapartor`.There you can modify the comparison criteria for sorting..

Comment: I don't think there is a reason to downvote this post.

Comment: i am poor in collections. i donno how to use comparator

Comment: @user1912935 This is the time to learn how to use it.

Comment: s thats true. But i dont have that much time to learn and solve this.. please help me.. i tried with sorted set also..but vain..

Comment: @user1912935 your code is working fine for me. try to clean the project and try again. :)

Comment: doesn't any body realize the code actually works. I have tried it and get the OP's desired output .

Comment: @PermGenError i clean and built the project again but no use.

Comment: Yes..the code works fine..but for more control over sorting you can use comparator..

Comment: Sorry for troubling you all. the issue is with the space. i used trim before adding the elemants into arraylist.Now it is working fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and got the output:

```
02112-S1529
02112-S1530
02112-S1531
```

Also, you have make your iterator generic

**Generics 101:** `don't use Raw type in new code`

```
Iterator<String> itr = gbosIdsList.iterator();
```

Comment: Please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176227/simple-way-to-sort-strings-in-the-alphabetical-order

Answer (score 0):

Define a comparator like this

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.util.Comparator#compare(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
        //Do your processing here 
        //and
        //return +1 if arg0 > arg1
        //return 0 if arg0 == arg1
        //return -1 if arg0 < arg1
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Then add this to your `sort`

```
List<String> gbosIdsList = new ArrayList<String>();
//add values
Collections.sort(gbosIdsList,new  MyComparator());
```

FYR you can read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29)