# Sort a String array in java (special way)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, uppercase, lowercase

I have a problem doing this since I need to sort it in this way:

Before:

```
{aAbB, abBA, AaBb}
```

After:

```
{AaBb, aAbB, abBA}
```

The idea is sorting a uppercase letter right before it's lowercase version, and that with every letter.
I'm actually using a Collator for Spanish (problems with the 'ñ') and set it's strength to PRIMARY so I can compare if two words are equal not having care of capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
private static Comparator<String> ALPHABETICAL_ORDER = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        int res = String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(str1, str2);
        if (res == 0) {
            res = (str1.compareTo(str2)==0) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return res;
    }
};

Collections.sort(list, ALPHABETICAL_ORDER);
```

Inspired from: [Simple way to sort strings in the (case sensitive) alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176227/simple-way-to-sort-strings-in-the-alphabetical-order)

Answer (score 0):

This produces the desired result.

```
Arrays.sort(stringArray)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.