# Java Inserting Names ~ CompareTo

Tags: java, sorting, compareto

I am trying to write a sorting program that prompts input of names and sorts them alphabetically, capitalizing the first letter of each name. I am just simply lost.
I am thinking about splitting the code into two methods one for casing and the other for sorting.

Here's what I got so far for the capitalization bit:

```
titleCase(String x)

name = x

x.toLowerCase

x.substring(0;)toUppercase
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The end result should be something like this:

Enter the next name:

zeb

Enter the next name:

rita

Enter the next name:

SUE

Enter the next name:

adele

Enter the next name:

BarBara

Enter the next name:

StoP

[Adele, Barbara, Rita, Sue, Zeb]

Comment: So whats your question? We aren't just going to write some code for you. The little code you have provided  isn't even valid code

Comment: SO isn't really a place for dumping your homework assignment. What specifically are you having a problem with? Seems like you have the capitalization (somewhat) in hand. How will you collect them? A list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to sort strings in the (case sensitive) alphabetical order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176227/simple-way-to-sort-strings-in-the-case-sensitive-alphabetical-order)

Comment: @Ferrariman11 See my answer. It should solve your capitalization issue. If it helps you please mark it as a solution.

Comment: I am sorry. Maybe I should have clarified that I did not understand the alphabetical sorting part. I am trying to do this on my own with little teaching instruction.

Comment: You are trying to do this on your own yet you are coming here asking us to show you how to do it....?

Comment: Looking for some guidance to go forward in the right direction, not for you to write all my code. Nothing personal ~ redFIVE

Comment: Your first step should have been to google "sorting java". This isn't some obscure undocumented concept

Comment: Ok sorry for wasting your time @redFIVE

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method to take a string and loop over each character, setting them to the appropriate value:

```
public String titleCase(String toEdit) {
 String output = "";
 String toAppend = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < toEdit.length; i++) {
  if (i == 0) {
   toAppend = (toEdit.charAt(i) + "").toUpperCase();
  } else {
   toAppend = (toEdit.charAt(i) + "").toUpperCase();
  }
  output = output + toAppend;
 }
 return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping @nhouser9

Comment: @Ferrariman11 happy to help. if it answered your question it would be cool if you would mark it as an answer or upvote it to counteract the reputation i lost by getting downvoted by redFive

Answer (score 0):

Separating functionality is a good idea. The code snippet you wrote would fail, as is, due to syntax errors, however. It looks like you're on the right track for the casing portion.

Check out the String class in the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) and look at the `compareTo` function for comparing strings against each other for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Upper case the first character, turn it into a String, then take the rest of the name, lower case it then concatenate it to the first character. If there's only one character then just upper case it and make it a String.

```
public String nameCase(String name) {
  if(name == null || name.length() == 0) {
    return name;
  }
  if(name.length() > 1) {
    return String(Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0))).concat(name.substring(1).toLowerCase());
  } else {
    return String(Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0)));
  }
}
```