# Sort two different fields in one comparator

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to compare objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/best-way-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Hello i'm kinda new to programming and would like to ask help, my teacher created a class wherein the country, continent, and population is given. The desired output is to get the top 10 populated countries for each continent.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class WP {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WorldPop[] list = WorldPop.getList();
    int index;

    Arrays.sort(list, new PopComparator());

    for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%-53s %-20s %,14d\n", list[i].country, 
                       list[i].continent, list[i].population);
    }
}
}

class PopComparator implements Comparator<WorldPop> {
public int compare(WorldPop x, WorldPop y) {
    return x.population - y.population;
}
}

class TitleComparator implements Comparator<WorldPop> {
public int compare(WorldPop x, WorldPop y){
    return x.continent.compareTo(y.continent);
}
}
```

Comment: Check out the answer to this [question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/best-way-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried and where are you struggling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably sort each `Country` into a `Map<Continent, List<Country>>` by continent, and them simply sort each `List`

Answer (score 0):

First you can sort your list using below `Comparator` . now your list is sorted based on continental and countries  and then iterate them by calculating number of countries for each duplicate continental.

```
 Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<WorldPop>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(WorldPop x, WorldPop y) {
            int c;
            c = x.continent.compareTo(y.continent);
            if (c == 0)
               c = x.population .compareTo(y.population );
            return c;
        }
    });
```