# Sorting ArrayList of objects with two properties

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am using JDK 1.7 for my project. I have come across Huddle. I have an ArrayList of objects which have two properties: price (decimal) and product name (String). I need to sort the ArrayList, first by price and then by product name. I've tried to use the Java comparator, but I can only sort by one property.
Here is my code:

```
private static class PriceComparator implements Comparator<Product>{
 @Override
 public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
    return (p1.getPrice() > p2.getPrice() ) ? -1: (p1.getPrice() < p2.getPrice()) ?   
  1:0 ;
 }
```

}

This code only sort price, and not name.

Please i would apprecaite your help and example.

Thanks
Ish

Comment: show us the comperator that you have written...

Comment: The `Comparator` should actually be enough. Make sure you first compare by price and then by product name.

Comment: write a comparator, that compares the first Value and if these values are equal it compares the second value.

Comment: one similar post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/best-way-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using an Apache Commons library, Commons Lang has a [CompareToBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder.html). You can use it to easily compare multiple fields. Primitives are handled automatically, but you can pass an optional custom Comparator for each field as well.

```
public class Product implements Comparable<Product> {
    private float price;
    private String name;
    ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Product other) {
        return new CompareToBuilder()
            .append(getPrice(), other.getPrice())
            .append(getName(), other.getName())
            .toComparison();
    }
    ...
}
```

Then just call Collections.sort() on the List.

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
products.add(new Product("Adam's Product", 10.0))
products.add(new Product("Charlie's Product", 8.0))
products.add(new Product("Bob's Product", 8.0))
Collections.sort(products)
```

They will now be ordered as:

1. Bob's Product
2. Charlie's Product
3. Adam's Product