# Compare objects by different attributes without using comparators

Tags: java, oop, compare, design-patterns

Normally, comparators are the best option when you want to compare objects using different attributes
(see for example [How to compare objects by multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/best-way-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields)).
However, in my particular case I'm not sure about using comparators.

The problem is the following: I have defined a generic interface, called `Node<S>`, which is shared
by different components. There is also a `CostNode<S>` which extends the `Node<S>`, and a `ScoreNode<S>`
which extends `CostNode<S>`:

```
public interface Node<S> {
    S getS();
    // more methods...
}

public interface CostNode<S> extends Node<S> {
    // This method smells really bad
    int compareByCost(ComparableNode<S> node);
}

public interface ScoreNode<S> extends CostNode<S> {
    // int compareByCost(CostNode<S> node) (from CostNode<S>)
    int compareByScore(ScoreNode<S> node);
}
```

At this point, someone can argue: You don't need CostNode and ScoreNode, you
can use different comparators to compare nodes. That's ok. But the "problem" comes now:

I have a component, called Client, which uses ScoreNodes. Client requires a node factory,
provided by the user, which is responsible of creating ScoreNodes:

```
public class Client {
    // ...

    public Client(NodeFactory<S, ScoreNode<S>> nodeFactory){...}

    public void process() {

        while(...){
            S current = get();
            S old = getOld();
            // ...
            ScoreNode<S> next = this.nodeFactory.create(current,...));
            // Comparisons performed
            if (next.compareByCost(old) <=0){
                //...
            }
            if (next.compareByScore(old) > 0){
               // ...
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

As you can see, the behavior of comparing nodes is embedded into the nodes, and
is closely related to the factory used (different nodes requires a different factory 
and different comparators).

On the other hand, if I use comparators, I have to provide to the Client three components:
CostComparator, ScoreComparator and a NodeFactory. In this scenario, I can use only `Node<S>`
and forget about `CostNode<S>` and `ScoreNode<S>`:

```
public class ConcreteNodeCostComparator implements Comparator<Node<S>> {
    public int compare(Node<S> a, Node<S> b){
        return Double.compare(((ConcreteNode<S>)a).getCost(), ((ConcreteNode<S>)b).getCost()); 
    }
}

public class ConcreteNodeScoreComparator implements Comparator<Node<S>> {
    public int compare(Node<S> a, Node<S> b){
        return Double.compare(((ConcreteNode<S>)a).getScore(), ((ConcreteNode<S>)b).getScore()); 
    }
}
```

However, I don't really like this alternative, because in this case I have to provide two more components
to Client, when the comparison methods strongly depends on the nodes.

I think I'm missing something in this design. What do you think about?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Boune's answer in the thread you linked.
(http://tobega.blogspot.fr/2008/05/beautiful-enums.html)

You could use that kind of enum in your ScoreNode interface (or elsewhere) and use:

```
ScoreNode.Order.ByCost.compare(node1, node2);
ScoreNode.Order.ByScore.compare(node1, node2);
```

You don't have to provide any more components to your Client.

Comment: I saw the beautiful enum comparator in another post. Although the code is elegant, the problem is that I have to put the values to compare with inside the enum, killing reusability of the ScoreNode.