# Rewrite class for ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I am studying for a final, and im looking at a question from my midterm that i got wrong and honestly wasnt sure how to go about doing so. The question is as follows:

> Rewrite the Person class so that if you have an ArrayList of Person
>   objects, ArrayList, you can sort it using the Collections sort
>   method. The sort method should sort the list first by decreasing age
>   and then alphabetically (for people the same age).

The same code (Person class) that was provided in the question is below.

```
public class Person {
   public String name;
   public int age;
}
```

This was a midterm question so I had to hand write the code. I am wondering what is the efficient and proper way to answer this question. All answers or input is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can write a comparator class which compares two Person objects. [`SEE HERE`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/best-way-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Comment: @holoboy7 did you solve your problem

Comment: how is that a duplicate lol...

Comment: no it is not dupliucate.It need with two fields

Comment: @choloboy7 You're trying to sort an ArrayList of custom objects by property :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `Person` class implement the `Comparable` interface and provide an implementation for the `CompareTo` method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    public String name;
    public int age;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        return new Integer(this.age).compareTo(person.age);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.name = "Kevin";
        person.age = 28;
        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.name="Bob";
        person2.age = 40;
        Person person3 = new Person();
        person3.name="Joe";
        person3.age = 90;

        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people.add(person2);
        people.add(person3);
        people.add(person);

        Collections.sort((List<Person>)people);

        for(Person p:people){
            System.out.println(p.name);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to note @Kevin Bowersox answer that his answer sorts by ascending age and doesn't taken into account the second sort on name. Replace the compareTo with this to solve those two issues

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person person)
{
    int ageSort = new Integer(person.age).compareTo(this.age);

    // If the ages aren't the same
    if(ageSort != 0)
    {
        return ageSort;
    }

    // otherwise sort on name alphabetically
    return name.compareTo(person.name);
}
```