# ComparisonChain for multiple ways of sorting?

Tags: java, guava

I'm playing around with the Comparisonchain using this [example](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/17/clean-compareto-methods-with-google-guava/). But it just shows one way to sort these objects.

```
  public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
  private String name;
  private String family;
  private int calories;

  @Override
  public int compareTo( Fruit otherFruit ) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
      .compare( name, otherFruit.name )
      .compare( family, otherFruit.family )
      .compare( calories, otherFruit.calories )
      .result();
  }
}
```

I was wondering now if it is possible to sort based on the needs of the end user. How would I have to implement it, if the sorting criteria are not fixed? E.g. Someone wants to sort first by name, then by calories and that's it. The next one wants to sort by familiy, then by calories and then by name. and so on. People might also want to sort descending instead of ascending.

Can anybody give me some hints on how to solve it?

Comment: No I dont think there is an option of dynamic sort order readily available. You will have to build custom logic. Let us know if you need help in implementing custom logic

Comment: I'm not sure what you are thinking of ('implementing custom logic'). Yes, it would be nice to get some help.

Comment: Then the first question is: How should the sorting criteria be defined? Programmatically? Via a GUI? Via a configuration file? Annotations? ...

Comment: You need to think about the answers to questions raised above. And here is a link which will show you one way of doing it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206629/using-comparable-for-multiple-dynamic-fields-of-vo-in-java

Comment: the sorting criteria comes via GUI (multiple selection with option to define an order). I found a nice way, which seems to fit my needs here (just that I'm using a list for the getComparator-method): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421322/how-do-i-sort-a-list-with-multiple-sort-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Comparable` should implement exactly *one* way of comparing. Allowing it to be changed actually breaks the contract of `Comparable`, which requires that (to quote the Javadoc) `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))` for all `x` and `y`. If you can change the comparison that individual `Fruit` objects use, you can have an object `x` that says it's greater than `y`, while `y` says it's greater than `x`, and so on. Imagine if you have a `List<Fruit>` containing objects that are each configured to use a different sort order... trying to sort that list would just be chaos and not produce anything useful.

If you want multiple alternative ways of sorting, create `Comparator`s implementing each of those ways and expose them to users in some way. Then a single `Comparator` can be passed to the sort method (or `TreeSet` constructor, or whatever), ensuring that all comparisons use that logic.