# How can I sort a Java list using two different values?

Tags: java, sorting

```
public void sortLeagueTable(List<LeagueTableItem> table) {
    Collections.sort(table, new Comparator<LeagueTableItem>(){
        public int compare(LeagueTableItem o1, LeagueTableItem o2){
            return o2.getPoints() - o1.getPoints();
        }
    });
}
```

This code sorts two lists based on the value of the object called points. After I sort it based on the value `point` I want to sort it again based on the value `goalScored`. So, if the points of two teams are equal, I want to sort it again based on the `goalScored` value.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Comparable for multiple dynamic fields of VO in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206629/using-comparable-for-multiple-dynamic-fields-of-vo-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another condition to your comparator:

```
public int compare(LeagueTableItem o1, LeagueTableItem o2){
     int diff = o2.getPoints() - o1.getPoints();
     if (diff == 0) {
        diff = o2.goalScored() - o1.goalScored();
     }
     return diff;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Java 8's enhancements to the `Comparator` interface give you a pretty elegant way of achieving this:

```
table.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(LeagueTableItem::getPoints)
                     .thenComparingInt(LeagueTableItem::goalScored));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int compare(LeagueTableItem o1, LeagueTableItem o2) {
        if (o2.getPoints() == o1.getPoints()) {

            return o2.goalsScored() - o1.goalsScored();
        } else {
            return o2.getPoints() - o1.getPoints();
        }
    }
```

First it gets the o1 and o2's points and compare them. If they are equal, the if statement proceed to calculate which **o** has more goals scored and returns the result, else if the points are NOT equal it returns the result.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.