# How to sort Arraylist by many catogories

Tags: java, arraylist, overriding, compareto

Here I' comparing but only the title of the book. But after that I want to compare it with the author and the book no. As I know there must be only one override method. So please help me on this.

```
@Override

public int compareTo(Book bk) {

return this.bookTitle.compareTo(bk.bookTitle);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement different comparators for different sorting types and pass them for Collections.Sort method. See [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
Class AuthorSort implements Comparator<Book>
{

   public int compare(Book b1, Book b2){
       // do comparision on Author
    }

}
```

Implements Book Number Sorting

```
Class BookNoSort implements Comparator<Book>
{

   public int compare(Book b1, Book b2){
       // do comparision on Book Number
    }

}
```

Call Sort method on Collections class and provide different implentation

```
Collections.sort(list, new BookNumberSort());
Collections.sort(list, new AuthorSort());
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Comparator

```
class BookAuthorComparator implements Comparator<Book>{
    public int compare(Book b1, Book b2){
        return b1.getAuthor().compareTo(b2.getAuthor());
    }
}

Collections.sort(bookList, new BookAuthorCompartor());
```

Comment: How can I get 2 return types for title and author seperatly

Comment: what do you mean by 2 return types? what is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Write your own Comparator by implementing Compareable

Refer this 
[How to compare objects by multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/best-way-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 0):

you could use anonymous inner class as:

```
Collections.sort(bookList, new Comparator<Book>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Book b1, Book b2) {
            return b1.property.compare(b2.property);
        }
    });
```

if you want sorting to be performed on title or author just change

```
return b1.getTitle().compare(b2.getTitle());
```

or

```
return b1.getAuthor().compare(b2.getAuthor());
```