# Sorting a ArrayList<float[]> on two attributes within the float array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I am making use of the following ArrayList: `ArrayList<float[]> notes = new ArrayList<float[]>();`

I managed to perform the sorting on the first element of the float[] array without any problem. Now I am also trying to sort the ArrayList on  using a second attributes. However I cannot manage to sort the list again on the second element of the float arrays ie. `float[1]`.

Any hints?

Comment: Arrays.sort should work....

Comment: what do you mean? `float[]` is an array of primitive `float`s (not Objects)

Comment: Hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/how-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields/369867#369867

Comment: @ryekayo He is trying to sort the List that contains arrays not the arrays in each list, so you need to use Collections.sort not Arrays.sort

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) to sort the array and then use your own [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to specify how you want to sort the values.

```
ArrayList<float[]> notes = new ArrayList<float[]>();
//adding some dummy data to the list
notes.add(new float[]{5f,6f,1f});
notes.add(new float[]{5f,2f,1f});
notes.add(new float[]{5f,1f,1f});

//Use Collections.sort to sort Ascending values on the second value in the float arrays
Collections.sort(notes, new Comparator<float[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(float[] o1, float[] o2) {
        if (o1[1] > o2[1]){
            return 1;
        }else if(o1[1] < o2[1]){
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
});

//Output the values
for (float[] f : notes){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f));
}
```

Output:

```
[5.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[5.0, 2.0, 1.0]
[5.0, 6.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: Hint for simpler comparison: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare%28float,%20float%29