# Sort arrayList based on both date and ID

Tags: java, sorting

i want to sort the list of task,first by date and then by taskID
below is the code

```
ArrayList<fullist> taskdet = new ArrayList<fullist>();
public static class fullist
      {        

 public int date;
 public int id;

 public fullist(int id, int date) {

        this.date = date;
        this.id = id;
    }



}
```

i used the Collections.sort method to sort but through this i can sort either by date or ID at a time.
if sort by date

```
Collections.sort(taskdet, new Comparator<fullist>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(fullist o1, fullist o2) {
            //if(o1)
            return Integer.compare(o1.date, o2.date);
        }
    });
```

This is the output displayed :

```
 day 19 ID 2
 day 19 ID 1
 day 19 ID 3
 day 20 ID 2
 day 20 ID 1
 day 20 ID 3
```

if sort by ID.

```
Collections.sort(taskdet, new Comparator<fullist>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(fullist o1, fullist o2) {
            //if(o1)
            return Integer.compare(o1.date, o2.date);
        }
    });
```

This is the output displayed :

```
 day 20 ID 1
 day 19 ID 1
 day 19 ID 2
 day 20 ID 2
 day 20 ID 3
 day 19 ID 3
```

but output should be :

```
day 19 ID 1
day 19 ID 2
day 19 ID 3
day 20 ID 1
day 20 ID 2
day 20 ID 3
```

Comment: This is probably the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/369867/1008519

Comment: collections.sort is stable, so you can sort successively. Also you can find how you want to compare you 2 objects so that it does what you want in your comparator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
Collections.sort(taskdet, new Comparator<Fullist>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(fullist o1, fullist o2) {                
            int res = Integer.compare(o1.date, o2.date);
            if(res == 0)
                return o1.id - o2.id
            return res;
        }
    });
```

Comment: side note: using `o1.id - o2.id` exposes you to a risk of overflow, with unpredicted results.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Java 8 you can write:

```
taskdet.sort(comparingInt(fullist::getDate).thenComparingInt(fullist::getId));
```

This assumes you have a `getDate` and `getId` getters and this static import:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;
```

Comment: If we have Java 8  we can simply write `list.sort(comparator)` instead of `Collections.sort(list,comparator)`.

Comment: Consider using `comparingInt(...).thenComparingInt(...)` since you're dealing with primitives..

Answer (score 2):

An other nice solution is to use Guava [ComparisonChain](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html):

```
public int compare(fullist o1, fullist o2) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
                          .compare(o1.date, o2.date)
                          .compare(o1.id, o2.id)
                          .result();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need your `Comparator` to compare the `id` values if the `date` values are the same.

```
@Override
public int compare(fullist o1, fullist o2) {
    int comp = Integer.compare(o1.date, o2.date);
    if (comp == 0)
    {
        comp = Integer.compare(o1.id, o2.id);
    }
    return comp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java8:

```
    taskdet.sort((a, b) -> {
        int r = a.date - b.date;
        return r == 0 ? r : a.id - b.id;
    });
```