# Java make custom object comparable?

Tags: java

I have the object below.

```
public class Coords {

    public int x;
    public int z;

    public Coords(int x, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.z = z;
    }

}
```

How can this implement Compareable?
Im not sure what the **compareTo** method should be doing.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to compare between two `Coords` objects?

Comment: im using a ConcurrentSkipList set with Coords as the object and the exception Coords cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable is thrown

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare objects by multiple fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/how-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare `x` and then compare `z` (alternatively, `z` and then `x`). Also, I suggest you override `toString`. Something like,

```
public class Coords implements Comparable<Coords> {
    public int x;
    public int z;

    public Coords(int x, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.z = z;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Coords o) {
        if (this.x == o.x) {
            if (this.z == o.z) {
                return 0;
            }
            return this.z < o.z ? -1 : 1;               
        }
        return this.x < o.x ? -1 : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{%d, %d}", x, z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details of [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29):

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

I'd suggest something like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Coords other) {
    return this.x == other.x ? (this.z == other.z ? 0 : this.z - other.z) : this.x - other.x
```

You can make `z` more significant if you switch them.