# Sort a Collection list with two numeric parts of string in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

Could any one suggest idea to sort the list accordingly :
suppose the List contains :

```
-SP001 of 2017
-SP002 of 2015
-SP001 of 2015
-SP001 of 2016
-SP005 of 2015
-SP003 of 2015
```

The the out put should be (List must contain in the below order) :

```
-SP001 of 2015
-SP002 of 2015
-SP003 of 2015
-SP005 of 2015
-SP001 of 2016
-SP001 of 2017
```

here i need to sort according to number part as well as year part.
I have tried collection sort but it gives out put like :

```
[SP001 of 2015, SP001 of 2016, SP001 of 2017, SP002 of 2015, SP003 of 2015, SP005 of 2015]
```

Comment: Write your own comperator.

Comment: write a `Comperator` that does extract the numbers and sorts them according to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare objects by multiple fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/how-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Comment: Or better: parse the strings upfront to objects with two integers, and sort those objects.

Comment: @Justin Are you aware you can accept answer which solves your problem?

Comment: @Justin You can click on the `tick` beside the answer which helps you best. You get will 2 pts in return.

Comment: @user3437460 : Thanks.. will do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: First split the strings and then compare the third element of array.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("-SP005 of 2015");
list.add("-SP001 of 2017");
list.add("-SP003 of 2015");
list.add("-SP001 of 2015");
list.add("-SP001 of 2016");
list.add("-SP002 of 2015");

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int result = o1.split(" ")[2].compareTo(o2.split(" ")[2]);
        if (result == 0) {// if the years are the same, then compare with first element
            return o1.split(" ")[0].compareTo(o2.split(" ")[0]);
        }
        return result;
    }
});

System.out.println("list = " + list);
```

And it is the result:

```
list = [
-SP001 of 2015, 
-SP002 of 2015, 
-SP003 of 2015, 
-SP005 of 2015, 
-SP001 of 2016, 
-SP001 of 2017
]
```

Comment: I am getting Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above, I am getting this coz am using jdk 7

Comment: Thanks, but i have already tried the above, thats not give me exact answer..List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add("-SP001 of 2017");
  list.add("-SP002 of 2015");
  list.add("-SP001 of 2016");
  list.add("-SP005 of 2015");
  list.add("-SP003 of 2015");

Comment: What do you mean by 'not give me exact answer' the result I got from the code I already posted in the answer, it must work.

Comment: sp01 of 2015,sp02 of 2015,sp01 of 2016,sp03 of 2016,sp01 of 2017, this is the example order i needed, thanks for your answers.

Comment: OK, then the output is exactly what you want, if you see the answer, it is ordered by year, in ascending order.

Comment: yes, but for me sorting must not be with year alone... if sp001 of 2015 means need to sort according to 001 and 2015. in your answer 003 is after 005.

Comment: The answer has been updated again, now it is what you were looking for. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

### For [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

---

You may use two `Comparator<String>` and the method `thenComparing` within the `Collections#sort` method

The first comparator will compare the years, while the second will compare the second String and so directly the first part of each one.

```
Comparator<String> comp1 = (x, y) -> x.split(" ")[2].compareTo(y.split(" ")[2]);
Comparator<String> comp2 = (x, y) -> x.compareTo(y);

Collections.sort(list, comp1.thenComparing(comp2));

System.out.println(list);
```

---

### Output

```
[SP001 of 2015, SP002 of 2015, SP003 of 2015, SP005 of 2015, SP001 of 2016, SP001 of 2017]
```

Comment: :Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above, I am getting this coz am using jdk 7

Comment: @Justin Ok, I'm letting my answer though in case someone might need it or if you upgrade to jdk 8