# Java ArrayList sort with multi object

Tags: java, arraylist

There 4 type class:
Class A,Class B,Class C, Class D

```
Class attribute:
Class A:aID,name,sequence
Class B,bID,amount,sequence
Class C,cID,price,sequence
Class D,dID,date,sequence
```

The attributes of those class is different. However, they have the same attribute "Sequence".

For example, i created a ArrayList to store those object.

```
item 1(Class A) = Sequence(4)
item 2(Class D) = Sequence(2)
item 3(Class C) = Sequence(3)
item 4(Class B) = Sequence(1)
item 5(Class C) = Sequence(5)
```

How can i sort this list into this order?

```
item 1(Class B) = Sequence(1)
item 2(Class D) = Sequence(2)
item 3(Class C) = Sequence(3)
item 4(Class A) = Sequence(4)
item 5(Class C) = Sequence(5)
```

Comment: need clarification, please edit and provide more details about the classes and attributes

Comment: Do your classes implement a common interface? if not, why not?

Comment: Try using `Comparator` or check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25501226/4790490).

Comment: Do the classes A, B, C and D share a common parent-class? If yes, you could use a Comparator<Parent> to sort them by Sequence. [Here is an example of how a Comparator is used to order an Employee-object by Salary.](http://java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/arraylist/sort-comparator/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The can think in two ways to archieve what you want:

#### Your own method

It's not hard to create a method to do the sorting, but you would have to implement your own sorting algorithm.

#### Collections.sort

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property) you can find a fine example on the accepted answer, you could just use that with a little difference:

**If** all your classes extend the same class or implement the same interface, instead of `MyObject` you can use the parent class. (They **SHOULD** implement a common interface).

**Else**, you can just use `Object` and chain several "instanceof" and casts to the said class. Anyway, look the **if**, I can't think of any situation where it wouldn't be the best choice.