# Manual binary search by passing just an object

Tags: java, algorithm, search

Currently stuck on a problem with binary search that is asking me to pass one parameter with is an object.
But is it possible to do this?? Normally I would use two parameters for a problem like this. 
Normally with binary search I use-->

```
int binarySearch(int[] list, int searchItem) 
{ 
int mid=0; 
int start=0; 
int end=list.length-1; 
boolean found=false; 

//Loop until found or end of list. 
while (start <= end && !found) 
{ 
mid = (start + end) / 2; 
if (list[mid] == searchItem)
  found = true;
else 
  if (list[mid] > searchItem) 
    end = mid - 1;
  else 
    start = mid + 1;
}
if(found) 
return mid;
else 
 return(-1);
}
```

But is it possible to just pass in one parameter like this?? I need to search an array list.

```
  public int binarySearch(Moon searchItem){
  int mid = 0;
  int start = 0;
  int end = moons.size() -1;
  boolean found = false;

  while(start <= end && !found){
      mid = (start + end) / 2;
      if(moons.get(mid).equals(searchItem)){
          found = true;
      }
      else{
          if(???)) {
          }
          else
            etc etc     
      }    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you can replace `list[mid]` with `moons.get(mid)` then you can do it twice! replace your `???` with `moons.get(mid)` as well! (And then as Azodious mentioned you need to compare objects, but you haven't really posted a lot of context - it looks like you got a lot of code from someone so perhaps your Moon already has a `compareTo` method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should go through this question: [How to compare objects by multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/how-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Then, implement `Comparable` to `Moon` class. If you can't change Moon class, then you've to create `Comparator`.

You'll need to override `compareTo` method in Moon class which can be used in place of `???` in your question.

Comment: Ah thanks...I already have an overrided compareTo(), to compare the radius of the objects.