# Comparator for Treemap

Tags: java

How correctly to implement the Comparator for the Treemap?
It should:
 1. Sort words by the length of the line in descending order.
 2. Words of equal length sort alphabetically.

```
class Test implements Comparator<String> {

    public static SortedMap<String, String> doSort(String str) {
        Comparator<String> comparator = new Test();
        SortedMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>(comparator);

        //do something to input String

        return map;
    }


    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2)
    {
        return o2.length() - o1.length();
    }
}
```

is that enough?
How to add alphabet sorting in the second turn?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare objects by multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/how-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Comment: I don't need several fields. I need 2 methods of sorting: 1.Length. 2.Alphabet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java 8+, you could write this with a lambda such as

```
Comparator<String> comparator = (a,b) -> {
    int r = Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length());
    if (r != 0) {
        return r;
    }
    return a.compareTo(b);
};
```

In Java 7 and earlier, it might do

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        int r = Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length());
        if (r != 0) {
            return r;
        }
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
};
```

Comment: So sorry, I don't see 2 sorting, only 1: the length of the word. I need two: 1.The length of the word. 2.Alphabet.
Or does it mean that Treemap itself sorts the comparison string length? Unfortunately, in my case it doesn't work.

Comment: The `return a.compareTo(b);` when `r == 0` is comparing alphabetically. This is exactly what you asked for.