# Sorting with Apache Commons CompareToBuilder descending order

Tags: java, apache, sorting, apache-commons

I want to sort a collection by multiple fields (some of them in descending order) using Apache Commons CompareToBuilder

Ie:

```
Collections.sort(pizzas, new Comparator<Pizza>() {  
    @Override  
    public int compare(Pizza p1, Pizza p2) {  
        return new CompareToBuilder().append(p1.size, p2.size).append(p1.nrOfToppings, p2.nrOfToppings).append(p1.name, p2.name).toComparison();  
    }  
});
```

The default behavior for null values (ie. z, b, a, 1, null) is still true? 
Or null values comes first in this case?

[How to compare objects by multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/how-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields/46708190#46708190)

Answer (score 1):

Try this on for size. To sort a single parameter descending, all you have to do is swap the parameters in the builder's append method (`b.append(p2.name, p1.name)` instead of `b.append(p2.name, p1.name)`). A little extra logic is required to put nulls the opposite of where they would naturally go (first when sorting asc, last when sorting desc).

```
final boolean nullsLast = ...
Collections.sort(pizzas, new Comparator<Pizza>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Pizza p1, Pizza p2) {
        CompareToBuilder b = new CompareToBuilder()
            .append(p2.size, p1.size) // p2 as first parameter to sort desc, nulls last
            .append(p1.nrOfToppings, p2.nrOfToppings); // sort nrOfToppings asc, nulls first
        // sort name asc, nulls first or last depending on parameter
        if (nullsLast && p1.name == null) {
            b.append(p2.name, p1.name); // null last
        }
        else {
            b.append(p1.name, p2.name); // null first
        }

        return b.toComparison();
    }
});
```