# Java Sorting Objects using Comparable with more than one sorting criteria

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I have recently started learning Java. I was looking at Comparable and Comparator. One of the difference I read was "when you have one sorting criteria, use comparable interface and for more than one use Comparator". 
But for Comparable I can use multiple sorting criteria's too like below :

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{
    public int empID;
    public int empStartDate;

    public int compareTo(Employee empObj){
        int result = this.empID - empObj.empID;
        if(result == 0){
            result = this.empStartDate - empObj.empStartDate;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I do understand other differences they have. But I am kind of stuck on this difference (Single and multiple sorting criteria). 
Please correct me if I am wrong. Why is Comparable recommended for single sorting criteria if we can do using above approach? Could someone please explain me with an example? Thank you!

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369512/how-to-compare-objects-by-multiple-fields

Answer (score 3):

> Why is `Comparable` recommended for single sorting criteria if we can do using above approach?

There is no generally accepted recommendation for that.

Wherever you read that is mistaken.

---

[`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) vs [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) is not at all about whether you're comparing one or many values.

An object can have (at most) one *natural order*. If it does, that natural order is implemented using `Comparable`. It is actually written in the javadoc of [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's *natural ordering*, and the class's `compareTo` method is referred to as its *natural comparison method*.

Whether or not the object has a natural order, (alternative) ordering can be implemented using `Comparator`.

Neither is about the complexity of the comparison being done.

---

*Unrelated:*

Do not calculate `compare` / `compareTo` result using integer subtraction, since it will fail if the two values are more than `MAX_VALUE` apart (numeric overflow).

Always use [`Integer.compare(x, y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)) when comparing `int` values (available since Java 7). Same for [`Long.compare​(x, y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#compare(long,long)).